Fix for CVE-2024-42154 - linux-image-aws
We got a critical finding in AWS Inspector for an EC2 instance.
Affected packages
Name: linux-image-aws
Installed version: 0:5.15.0.1068.74~20.04.1.X86_64
Fixed version: 0:5.15.0.1069.75~20.04.1
I ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade but that didn't upgrade linux-image-aws
I tried sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade linux-image-aws but it still shows
linux-image-aws is already the newest version (5.15.0.1068.74~20.04.1).

What do I need to do to get the 0:5.15.0.1069.75~20.04.1 version?

Did you check the Ubuntu CVE Tracker?

Did you check apt policy linux-image-aws or apt-cache madison linux-image-aws to see if that version is available and appropriate for your release of Ubuntu? Sometimes third-party tools are incorrect.

Ubuntu CVE Tracker shows that it's Pending - that might be why I can't get it.
apt-cache madison linux-image-aws does not show 0:5.15.0.1069.75~20.04.1

Aha. It's in the -proposed pocket. It exists, but is still in testing.

You can find the package you need at the link
https://ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=linux-image-aws
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa 
sudo apt update
sudo apt-cache madison linux-image-aws 
sudo apt-get install linux-aws={version}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
